# comparação de containers

Tags: c++

o seguinte código funciona bem ->

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> mec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

if (vec == mec)
{
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}
```

existe uma sobrecarga do operador `==` pro vector, e os tipos no vector também
precisam ter um operador `==`, pois o functor `std::equal_to<>` é utilizado
na comparação dos elementos, mas eu não consigo entender porque o seguinte
código não compila ->

```
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(int x) : x(x)
    {

    }

    bool operator==(const Stack& e)
    {
        return this->x == e.x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Stack> vec = { Stack(1), Stack(2), Stack(3) };
    std::vector<Stack> mec = { Stack(1), Stack(2), Stack(3) };

    if ( vec == mec)
    {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

o visual studio mostra os seguintes 2 erros:

**Falha em especializar template de função 'unknown-type std::equal_to::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'**

**'operator __surrogate_func': nenhuma função sobrecarregada correspondente encontrada**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou a palavra reservada `const` no fim da declaração do operador `==`:

```
bool operator==(const Stack& e) const
{                             //  ^-----aqui
    ...
}
```

[Veja no Ideone como desta forma já funciona](https://ideone.com/2oD79K)

Comment: realmente era isso, não achei que esse qualificador fosse a causa do erro.. Valeu